# How to check the string value of an argument passed to expect script?

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm writing a expect script that takes command line arguments.  I would like to be able to detect whether the first argument is "--help" and print a Usage string then. Otherwise use the argument as a port number with a specific default (let's say 1818).

I tried this code that fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

if {[llength $argv] != 1} {
    puts "No Port number specified, defaulting to port 1818."
    set port 1818
} else {
    if {[lindex $argv 0] eq "--help"} {
        puts "Usage: testit [--help] [port]"
        exit
    } else {
        set port [lindex $argv 0]
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
invalid command name "--help"
    while executing
"--help"
    invoked from within
"if {[llength $argv] != 1} {
    puts "No Port number specified, defaulting to port 1818."
    set port 1818
} else {
    if {[lindex $argv 0] eq "--he..."
```

Obviously it is trying to interpret the content of the "--help" string while I'm trying to make the script compare the value of argument 0 to "--help".

What is wrong in the above logic or syntax?

I tried using other strings, like "help" instead of "--help" but the outcome is the same.

I'm not that familiar with expect and tcl, but I tried the expression in tclsh and the same thing happens there. So this issue has to do with invalid tcl code.  The following tcsh session shows that the syntax `if {$variable=="--help"} {...}` is OK, but removing the white space in my string comparison attempt above does not solve the problem.

Here's the tcsh session:

```
% set v1 "--help"
--help
% if [v1 == "--help'] { puts "allo"}
extra characters after close-quote
% if [v1 == "--help"] { puts "allo"}
invalid command name "v1"
% if [$v1 == "--help"] { puts "allo"}
invalid command name "--help"
% if $v1 == help {puts "allo"}
invalid bareword "help"
in expression "--help";
should be "$help" or "{help}" or "help(...)" or ...
% if $v1 == "--help" {puts "allo"}
invalid bareword "help"
in expression "--help";
should be "$help" or "{help}" or "help(...)" or ...
% if {$v1=="--help"} {puts "allo"}
allo
%
```

Comment: The problem is not the string compare, but the error reporting: `puts "Usage: testit [--help] [port]"`. Try changing that to `puts {Usage: testit [--help] [port]}`.

Comment: Ah!  the [--help] inside the string is being interpreted, right?  And the error number is at the very first line of the entire expression, which makes it difficult to see what the problem is.  Thanks! That was it!

Comment: To handle options with a more tested module, investigate [`cmdline` from tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.md)

Comment: Thanks,  it's my first foray into the world of tcl/expect.  I'll have to read much more!

Comment: You can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) if you are more familiar with shell syntax.

Comment: Learning another language is always useful. I like John Ousterhout Philosophy of Software Design, so learning more what tcl can do will be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
    puts "Usage: testit [--help] [port]"
```

And the problem with it is that `[...]` does command substitution in that situation. You need to add a couple of backslashes in there to prevent that, like this:

```
    puts "Usage: testit \[--help] \[port]"
```

Or you can enclose the string in braces to inhibit *all* substitutions:

```
    puts {Usage: testit [--help] [port]}
```

Either will work (and they'll get compiled to exactly the same thing so use whichever you prefer).